# Is there a way to non-intrusively track the execution of MySQL statements

Tags: mysql, linux, perf, strace

I have encountered a SQL execution failure problem in the last few days. It wastes a long time to trace and debug its function calls through GDB. Is there a better way to non-intrusively track the execution of MySQL Specific SQL statement, get the code function call during the execution of the statement?

I have considered perf or strace tools, but not very good.

Platform limited：Linux

Comment: [MySQL INSPECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) is probably what you looking for. For tracking code & query I use build-in tool in Nette framework called [Tracy](https://tracy.nette.org/en/dumper) (can be used standalone)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me@Facty